# How to find partial derivative if given antiderivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

In my book exercise I need to find $\frac{მz}{მx}$, if $F(xz,yz)=0$
I try to do it like that
$$ F'_{xz}(d(xz))+F'_{yz}(d(yz))=0 $$
$$ F'_{xz}(z+x\frac{მz}{მx})+F'_{yz}(z\frac{მy}{მx}+y\frac{მz}{მx})=0 $$
express from it $\frac{მz}{მx}$
$$ \frac{მz}{მx}=\frac{-F'_{xz}*z-F'_{yz}*z\frac{მy}{მx}}{F'_{xz}*x+F'_{yz}*y} $$
but answer in the end of the book don't have part with $\frac{მy}{მx}$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac {\partial}{\partial u}F(u,v)=F_1(u,v),\frac {\partial}{\partial v}F(u,v)=F_2(u,v).$$ The given equation defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y.$ By the chain rule, $$F_1(xz,yz)(z+x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})+F_2(xz,yz)(y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})=0.$$
$$F_1(xz,yz)z+F_1(xz,yz)x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+F_2(xz,yz)(y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})=0.$$ $$(F_1(xz,yz)x+F_2(xz,yz)y)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-F_1(xz,yz)z$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{F_1(xz,yz)z}{F_1(xz,yz)x+F_2(xz,yz)y}$$ 
provided $F_1(xz,yz)x+F_2(xz,yz)y \ne 0.$

Comment: what to we apply chain rule?

Comment: @Computation: Let u=xz,v=yz.. Then, since z is a function of  x and y, both u and v are functions of x and y. Hold y fixed and take the derivative of F(u,v) with respect to x by the chain rule,